# Parse curl response in bash without jq

Tags: json, bash, curl

I'm trying to parse an array, child of array, in json response returned from a curl request in bash. Unfortunately i can't use `jq` because it can't be installed on production servers.
I've try using awk or sed in curl request but result is empty. So i'm using grep with regex but i can't iterate properly.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PARAM=$1

# Run environment variables
export $(grep -v '^#' ${PWD}/.env | xargs)

# Step 1 : Get JWT Token
TOKEN=$(curl \
  --silent \
  --request POST "${URL_API}"/login \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d '{"username": "'${API_USERNAME}'", "password": "'${API_PWD}'" }' \
  | sed -n 's|.*"token":"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p'
)

# Step 2 curl GET request and put it in json file
JSON_RESULT=$(curl \
  --silent \
  --output test.json \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer '${TOKEN}'' \
  --request GET "${URL_API}"/sites/list?value="${PARAM}" \
)
```

Json response from API :

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 212,
      "list": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3",
        "value4"
      ],

      "createdAt": "2023-02-09T15:47:38+01:00",
      "foo": "bar",
      "foo2": "ba2r",
    }
  ],
  "metas": {
    "code": 200,
    "count": 1,
    "total": 5
  }
}
```

I want as array type the result of "list" key.
I'm trying like this :

```bash
# Step 3 retrieve data in "list" sub-key in json
TEST=$(grep -zoP '"list":\s*\K[^\s]*(?=\s*,)' test.json)
echo ${TEST}
```

Display :

```
> scripts/test.sh: line 35: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
["value1","value2","value3","value4"]
```

How can parse this as array for doing something like this :

```bash
# step 4 iterate
IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$TEST"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
  echo $i
done
```

?

Comment: python includes json support in standard library and is often already available on many systems.  You should really just tell your admins to install `jq` imho, but python may be a good workaround.  Similarly, a Go executable static compiled (without CGo) doesn't have any system dependencies besides CA certificates.

Comment: I know and i already asked but i'm working for a public institute, so it's very complicated to have positive request...and when it's accepted, it took many days to have it.

Comment: @erik258 `jq` itself is similarly self-contained: "jq is written in portable C, and it has zero runtime dependencies. You can download a single binary, scp it to a far away machine of the same type, and expect it to work."

Comment: @Astro-Otter Don't conflate "can't be installed" with "I haven't asked for it to be installed yet." And if it is refused, ask what JSON parser you *can* use, because `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc are all unsuitable.

Comment: jq is not self contained; at least the default install on ubuntu links against standard libraries.  Guess it depends what you mean by "system dependencies".

Comment: Again, have you ruled out Python yet? It's arguably the best tool for the job, and lots of our other "how do I parse JSON from shell?" questions have answers that show how to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`, using a file as input -

```
$: sed -nE 'H; ${x; s/[ \n]+//g; s/^.*"list":\[/\[/;s/\].*/]/;p;}' file
["value1","value2","value3","value4"]
```

This works even if the file has no embedded spaces or newlines.

Breakout:

-nE just stacks `-n` and `-E`.
`-n` says `n`o output unless explicitly requested.
`-E` ues `E`xtended pattern matching, so you don't have to backslash-quote your square brackets.

In the actual command list,
`H;` stacks each line of input onto the `H`old buffer.
No other commands are executed on any line but the last.

`${...}` means "on the last line, do these commands..."

`x` e`x`changes the input buffer and the `H`old buffer, putting all those lines you saved into the workspace.

`s/[ \n]+//g` will `s`ubstitute spaces and newlines with nothing `g`lobally across the buffer, stacking it all into one long line with any spaces removed.

`s/^.*"list":\[/\[/` says replace everything from the start(`^`) through the literal `list:[` with just `[`.

`s/\].*/]/` says replace everything from the remaining first `]` on with just `]`.

`p` will `p`rint the workspace buffer, which at this point should just be the data you asked for.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, i've found a solution :)

Comment: If that's the format you wanted for the output, I could have done that in the original `sed`. Be careful what you ask for, you might get it, lol

Answer (score 0):

Helped with @Paul Hodges solution i've found a way added with this [link](https://ingernet.github.io/bash/jq/json/2020/04/16/json-array-bash-array.html)

So:

```bash
# Paul Hodges solution above
LIST=$(sed -nE 'H; ${x; s/[ \n]+//g; s/^.*"list":\[/\[/;s/\].*/]/;p;}' test.json)

# Link
borkstring=$(echo $LIST | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/\, //g')
IFS=',' read -ra arr <<< "$borkstring"
for i in ${arr[@]}; do
    VALUE=${i//\"}
    echo "value: "$VALUE
done
```

Result :

```bash
value: value1
value: value2
value: value3
value: value4
```

And it's ok. maybe my code can be beautify more again :)

Comment: Did you prefer this format? Feels like an [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/). What's your end goal here?

Answer (score -4):

Use `while read` construction:

```
while read -r line; do

    [[ $line =~ list ]] && { add_to__list=true; continue; }
    [[ $add_to__list ]] && {
        [[ $line =~ \], ]] && break
        list+=( "${line//[\",]}" )
    }

done < json.file

echo "${list[@]}"
```

Result:

```
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

Comment: How can this possibly be an answer to the question? It isn't filtering the larger document to find only the list that OP intends to extract.

Comment: `$test` is considered as a string, not an array or list.  so i have : `key: ["value1","value2","value3","value4"]` . I need to cast it as array before but i don't know how-to

Comment: Then run through json file.

Comment: Looks like I've misunderstood the question. @Astro-Otter You need values of the "list" list to an array?